# How do we know that only these matrices commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Find all matrices that commute with \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}

I tried this: $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&c\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c&d\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$;
so equating them we get $c=0$ and $a=d$, so matrices that commute with $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ are $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\\ \end{bmatrix}$.

> I don't know how to conclude that these are only matrices that commute with $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: You have shown that if $c\not = 0$ then the top left and bottom right values of the two matrix multiplications will differ, and that if $a \not=d$ then the top right value of the two matrix multiplications will differ.  That convinces me.  If you wanted to add something, you might consider saying $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&b\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}  =\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\\ \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ so they do commute

Comment: Thanks for that comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that of all matrices, matrices that commute with $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ have this form.

To show this set of matrices of this form is **exactly** the set of matrices commuting with it, your last step is to show everything of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&a\\ \end{bmatrix}$ commutes with $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$, but that is easy. (The product in both orders is $\begin{bmatrix}0&a\\0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$)

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Big help. I was kind of thinking in other direction.